# leaflet.js - Creating a non-geographical map with geoJSON

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a geoJSON file containing some Voronoi polygons, which, as a `FeatureCollection`, describe a large landmass. Leaflet does have a tutorial on creating "[non-geographic maps.](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html)" The issue is that Leaflet appears to require a `TileLayer`, which I don't believe I can provide in this case, as the entire map is contained within the `.geojson` file.

Code example below:

```
let geoJsonText = loadFile("assets/maps/fuRepublic.json");
let mapDataObj = JSON.parse(geoJsonText)
console.log(mapDataObj)

let map = L.map("map", {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple
}).setView([100, 100], 13)

L.geoJSON(mapDataObj.features).addTo(map)
```

Comment: Leaflet doesn't require a TileLayer.  You can simply initialize the map as you've done, and you should have an empty map with a gray background (that is the default, but it can be changed).  Are you getting any errors with your code?

Comment: @SethLutske Yeah, I am getting the grey bg, except the Voronoi cells (geojson `feature`) . The line of code I have there at the bottom doesn’t appear to do anything. But thanks for the clarification - it helps!